# How to determine if the device is idle or if device is plugged in?

Tags: android

I have a service that will be started every once in a while via an AlarmManager.

When it starts I want to be able to check if the device is currently being used or if it is idle.

I could simply check if the screen is on, but it is possible that if the device was charging, or on a dock, that the screen could be on but not being used.  So that is is not a perfect method.

Is there a solid way determine that the device is idle?

If not, I figure if the device is plugged in, then in my case I could just carry on as if the device was idle.  However, I haven't been able to find a way to check if the phone is plugged in beyond capturing a Broadcast Intent.  Is there a way to just check without having to capture the broadcast intents continually?

Comment: What's your definition of idle?

Comment: Well I guess that would actually be up to debate, but I think in general it would be either A. The screen is off or B. The screen is on but it is locked on because it is plugged in or on a dock, and there is no user input from the screen, buttons or keys.

Comment: There are intents for all of those things.

Comment: @Falmarri I know I can receive notices when those states change but I only need to check once at the startup of the service.  I don't need to be constantly being notified about those states all the time, that seems like overkill.

Comment: You're not being constantly notifying. The broadcasts are sent regardless, it's rather trivial to listen for them. Trying to query the state is probably more work than listening for the broadcasts. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: @Falmarri Basically I want to say at the beginning of a service call something like if( screenIsOff || (screenIsOff && powerIsPluggedIn)){ do something }

Answer (score 0):

Android has an in built application called Autolock that can be customized.Please refer these links.
http://www.androidtapp.com/autolock/
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html
Hope this will help you.